# Counting Nodes with single child in BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

i have this question : implement function int countSingle(), which uses Breadth-First Traversal (BFT) in order to count how many nodes in the tree have a single child.

so the code below is what i thought of to solve it , is there another way of doing this or a more efficient that i missed ?

```
template <class T>
        int BST<T>::countSingle()
        {
            QueueDLL<BSTNode<T>*> queue;
            BSTNode<T>* node = root;

            // If the tree is empty, there will be no nodes to traverse.
            if(node == NULL) return -1;

            // Initially, put the root in the queue
            queue.Enqueue(node);
            int counter = 0 ;

            while(queue.IsEmpty() == false)
            {
                // Take a node out of the queue, process it and then insert
                // its children into the queue.
                node = queue.Dequeue();

                // if the node has one only one child wether its the left or the right , increase counter
                if((node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL) || (node->right== NULL && node->left!=NULL))
                    counter++;

                if(node->left != NULL)
                    queue.Enqueue(node->left);
                if(node->right != NULL)
                    queue.Enqueue(node->right);
            }
            return counter;
        }
```

Comment: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: Are you talking about count the number of leaf nodes in a tree?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews IIUC, it's not exactly that. It's the number of non-full non-leaf nodes.

Comment: yep its as what @AmiTavory said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty much OK. You can't really improve the complexity of what you did, since the number of operations is linear.

A few implementation points:

- Counting is a non-modifying operation, so you might want to consider `const`ing some stuff.
- You've basically implemented on your own something similar to what the compiler would do in recursion. If that's the intent - great (and there are some performance points in your favor). FYI, you could do this using recursion with very few LOCs.

Comment: i think that would be a Preorder DFT which can be made using  recursion but implemented using queue and this way its not recursion , i am not sure how i would go about this to make it in recursion tho